# Why doesn't one develop immunity to bacterial STIs?

Tags: immunology, bacteriology, antibiotics

Why doesn't one develop immunity to STIs such as Chlamydia/Gonorrhea and Syphilis even after the first exposure and treatment with antibiotics?